# How to convert a CSV file to 3D Text objects with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I want to take a simple CSV file and specify 2 rows then print them next to each other or below each other as separate objects:
eg. row 6 = NAME row 7 = TITLE

[image]

I am trying to read the list to reconstruct them as varying elements of a base title. I thought that I could place them on their own layers but I run out of layers quickly. So then I thought that I could allocate each pair to a series of frames or single frames to render.

Heres [my text file](http://www.pasteall.org/66751/text)

My code snippet reads out one row but I'm not sure how to iterate the rows and positions of each new row?

```
import bpy # THIS IS A MUST TO IMPORT ALL BLENDER PYTHON MODULE
import csv # IMPORT CSV MODULE

 # READ INPUT FILE

file = csv.reader(open('D:\daves\WBD\wbd filtered text', newline=''), delimiter=',')

curRow = [] #empty placeholder for current row

for idx, row in enumerate(file):
    if idx<22: # this is hard coded but you can use

        curRow = row

        # display first data index as string
        bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0,idx,0), rotation=(0,0,0))
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.font.delete()
        bpy.ops.font.text_insert(text=curRow[7], curRow[6])
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Try this:

```
import bpy # THIS IS A MUST TO IMPORT ALL BLENDER PYTHON MODULE
import csv # IMPORT CSV MODULE

# READ INPUT FILE

fp   = 'D:\daves\WBD\wbd filtered text'
file = csv.reader( open( fp, newline='' ), delimiter=',' )

nameIdx = 6 # Column index of text object's name
bodyIdx = 7 # Column index of text object's body (content)

for idx, row in enumerate( file ):
    if idx < 22: # this is hard coded but you can use
        # display first data index as string
        bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0,idx*2,0), rotation=(0,0,0))

        # After the line above is executed, the added text object becomes
        # the active object, referenced as the bpy.context.object
        # 't' will become a shortcut variable to access this object
        t = bpy.context.object

        # Access and alter the text object's name
        # This will be reflected in the outliner and object properties panel
        t.name = row[ nameIdx ]

        # Often in blender, the 'data' property holds specitic data
        # related to the object's type. For instance, a polygonal mesh
        # object's data property hold data about vertices, edges and polygons
        # among other things.
        # A text object's data stores the "body" property, which is the
        # actual text content of the text object. In this line we are 
        # updating the text content, and assigning it the name, a newline
        # character and then the title.
        t.data.body = row[ nameIdx ] + "\n" + row[ bodyIdx ].upper()
```

For simplicity's sake I combined the name and title to one text object (with a newline special character "\n" between them), but you can of course simply generate another text object and offset its position with a variation of this code.

Comment: Thank you TLousky, sorry not quite. I have added an image to illustrate my needs. I need to use both rows as text objects preferably named after their source. But thank you this was very informative!

Comment: @3pointedit, I edited my answer, see if this is more suited to your needs (and feel free to paraphrase this code, or elaborate further if not)

Comment: Thank you so much this is a great help. Can you explain the t = , t.name =, t.data.body = ? I don't understand how those definitions are used, I mean I see what they represent but don't get how they are used by the script? Are they python short cuts?

Comment: I tried to convert second line to uppercase but I'm not sure when to invoke bpy.ops.font.case_set(case='UPPER')

Comment: I tried to explain the code with long comments, hope it makes sense. Also makes the 2nd line uppercase.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for the excellent documentation. It's so obvious now. I really get stumped by formatting and data structures. It seems that every element that I want to play with isn't straightforward like a simple mesh is.

Comment: Last question I hope. I'm wondering about splitting Name and Description into separate text objects because I cannot control font size between them. How would I loop the generation of the additional element? When I repeat the bpy.object creation I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

not quite understood what you are asking for
i assume that you want every second element

- row_1 = row[::2] #every second starting from 0
- row_2 = row[1::2] #every second starting from 1

row[start:end:step] #defaults are [0:len(list):1]

or itterate through cycles every second element
for i in range(0, len(row), 2):