# Automatic text from file

Tags: text-object

Do you know how I can create text objects from a file or list like this?

Text           x        y       z
abc            876      232     12
bcb            365      345     23

etc

Thanks,

Owen

Comment: [similar topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49408/how-to-convert-a-csv-file-to-3d-text-objects-with-python)

Comment: similar yes, but I want to also place the text at specific locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes then maybe drag it to the location by hand to where you want it at..

or try to read the code... i mean the following line seems to be pretty much self explanatory and the author of the article mentioned above (duplicate) also tells you that you can easily offset the position to your liking using his code ;)

bpy.ops.object.text_add(location=(0,idx*2,0), rotation=(0,0,0))

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will have lots of loacations so looking to automate the placement. I can see that I should be able to insert the x, y and z fields from a csv file into the location values